# Solve integral (convolution) equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform, convolution, integral-equations

Given a function:
$u(t) = \exp\left( -\frac{At^2}{1+t}\right),$
$A>0, t>0,$

and an equation:
$\frac{d u(t)}{dt} = \int^{t}_0 \phi(t-\tau) u(\tau) d \tau .$

How to find a closed expression for $\phi(t)$?

Comment: Any properties of $\phi(t)$ would be interesting to know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking the Laplace transform on both sides of the equation
$$
s\,(\mathcal{L}u)(s)-u(0)=(\mathcal{L}\phi)(s)\,(\mathcal{L}u)(s),
$$
and
$$
(\mathcal{L}\phi)(s)=s-\frac{1}{(\mathcal{L}u)(s)},
$$
$$
\phi=\mathcal{L}^{-1}(s)-\mathcal{L}^{-1}\Bigl(\frac{1}{(\mathcal{L}u)(s)}\Bigr).
$$
Unfortunately it seems that there is no closed form for $\mathcal{L}(u)(s)$ in terms of elementary functions. A naïve asymptotic analysis suggests that
$$
(\mathcal{L}\phi)(s)\sim -A\quad\text{as }s\to\infty.
$$

Answer (score 4):

The first terms of the series expansion of the function $\phi(t)$ can be computed as shown in attachment :

[image]